# Spring-MVC Opening New Tabs For No Apparent Reason

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

there is a form with a submit that logs in a user

```
<div class="logInDIV">
    <form action="login.do" target="login.do" method="post">
        <span style="font-size:77%;">
            <label>email:</label>
            <input path="userName" cssClass="textfield" cssStyle="width:160px;" title="user name" name="userName" type="text" />
            &nbsp;
            <label>password:</label>
            <input path="password" cssClass="textfield" cssStyle="width:160px;" name="password" type="password" />
            &nbsp;
            <input value="Login" class="button" type="submit" style="margin-bottom:4px" />
        </span>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the corresponding controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doLogin(
            @RequestParam(value = "userName") String userName,
            @RequestParam(value = "password") String password,
            HttpSession session) {
        logger.info("login.do : userName=" + userName + ", password=" + password);

        SkunkPostUser skunkPostUser = null;
        try {
            skunkPostUser = profileService.getSkunkPostUser(userName, password);
        } catch (SkunkPostUserNotFoundException userNotFoundException) {
            return "login";
        }
        session.setAttribute("skunkPostUser", skunkPostUser);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

for some reason when I click the submit log in button it always opens a new tab, not sure why, does anyone know?

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML generated by the JSP?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `target` attribute from `<form>`. It specifies a [target window](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp), not a target URL.

Comment: thanks, I love making HTML errors then blaming it on Spring-MVC :o.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `target="login.do"`. It has a limited set of values: _blank, _self, _parent, _top, framename. Perhaps your value is interpreted as "_blank".